# Why is the call via stream() so much more time consuming than with if-clauses?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, data-structures, java-stream

Why is this method:

```
public static int howManyDifferentFields() {
    int difcolor = 0;
    difcolor++;
    if (fields[1] != fields[0]) {
        difcolor++;
    }
    if  (fields[2] != fields[1] && fields[2] != fields[0]) {
        difcolor++;
    }
    if (fields[3] != fields[2] && fields[3] != fields[1] && fields[3] != fields[0]) {
        difcolor++;
    }
    if (fields[4] != fields[3] && fields[4] != fields[2] && fields[4] != fields[1] && fields[4] != fields[0]) {
        difcolor++;
    }
    if (fields[5] != fields[4] && fields[5] != fields[3] && fields[5] != fields[2] && fields[5] != fields[1] && fields[5] != fields[0]) {
        difcolor++;
    }
    if (fields[6] != fields[5] && fields[6] != fields[4] && fields[6] != fields[3] && fields[6] != fields[2] && fields[6] != fields[1] && fields[6] != fields[0]) {
        difcolor++;
    }
    if (fields[7] != fields[6] && fields[7] != fields[5] && fields[7] != fields[4] && fields[7] != fields[3] && fields[7] != fields[2] && fields[7] != fields[1] && fields[7] != fields[0]) {
        difcolor++;
    }
    if (fields[8] != fields[7] && fields[8] != fields[6] && fields[8] != fields[5] && fields[8] != fields[4] && fields[8] != fields[3] && fields[8] != fields[2] && fields[8] != fields[1] && fields[8] != fields[0]) {
        difcolor++;
    }
    return difcolor;
}
```

so much faster than this?

```
public static int howManyDifferentFields2() {
    return (int) Arrays.stream(fields).distinct().count();
}
```

I would like to use the second way, because it is much less code. But this needs much more time! When I use the second method instead of the first, the program needs round about 8 times more time to finish.
What can I do? Can I somehow rewrite the first method to be effective as it is but with less code?
In my opinion the second method looks much better...

Comment: How do you measure the time? and do you think the first solution will be static for different array size and feasible for long array size?

Comment: I measure time with System.nanotime() at the begin and end of the program. I do not really understand your second question xD

Comment: Have you tried other methods, like direct conversion to a set without streams, or using nested loops? (Not an answer to the actual question, but might be a compromise between speed and readability)

Comment: he means the code does not scale when the possible number of items increases. The if statements get longer and longer. It's way too easy to make a mistake when typing the numbers. The stream solution may be slower but it works for any number of elements and is way more maintainable.

Comment: @tobias_k I tried it and it is a little bit faster but still slower than the first method.

Comment: Is `fields` always a 9-element array? And what element type?

Comment: I am a bit surprised that a nested loop should not be about as fast as this. However, both still have O(n²) complexity, whereas using a Set should only have O(n). But of course for such small sizes the overhead of creating a set, hashing etc. (and not to mention streams) may greatly outweight O(n) vs O(n²).

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Yes, always 9 element and its type is String (I know Strings should be compared with equals and not ==)

Answer (score 4):

Most people think streams are fast. But they’re not. There’s a lot of code backing them and it’s that hidden overhead that you’re hitting.

In the general case, a plain for loop is faster than a non-parallel stream (and even parallel streams when the number of elements is not large).

While streams make for neat and powerful code and have lots of benefits, for small streams performance isn’t one of them.

---

Your logic has O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity, but if n is fixed at 8 you’ll be OK and you can rewrite it as this near equivalent loop:

```
int difcolor = 8;
for (int i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (fields[i] == fields[j]) {
            difcolor--;
            break;
       }
    }
}
return difcolor;
```

Starting with a perfect score then decrementing on the first match improves the efficiency because it reduces the number of operations by exiting the inner loop as early as possible, similar to your use of short circuiting `&&`.

You could also use a Set, which has O(n) time complexity and is more compact, but with only 8 elements it will probably be slower than the loop above:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(); // assuming fields is a int[] 
int difcolor = 0;
for (int field : fields) {
    if (set.add(field)) {
        difcolor++;
    }
}
```

This works in a similar way to your stream version, but without the stream overhead.

If the elements were sorted, you could do it in a single pass comparing only neighbours.

Comment: So would you use the first method? I think it looks pretty ugly... do you have a better way to write it, but with the same efficiency?

Comment: @Protagor added a more elegant non stream version, with probably similar performance.

Answer (score 1):

You go with this solution:-
You can use map to store distinct values.
Also there will default, one count for difcolor so you can start from -1

```
Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int difcolor = 0;
        
        for(int i=0;i <fields.length;i++) {
            if(!myMap.containsKey(fields[i])) {
                difcolor++;
                myMap.put(fields[i], i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(difcolor);
```

Comment: Why use a Map if you never read the associated value, only the key? A Set will do what you want.

Comment: HashSet, the typical Set implementation, is also based on hashing, and its `contains()` method will also work without iterating, in nearly constant time.

Comment: Oh! yes, we can use HashSet @RalfKleberhoff